# Open another app that is already running

Tags: android, android-intent

With this code I can open another app:

```
Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgname);
startActivity(i);
```

But this doesnt work when the app was already launched and is running in the background. (After pressing the menu button)

How can I open/switch to a running app?

Comment: This should work even if the app is already launched and in the background (in that case it will bring the application to the foreground in whatever state it was left in). Have you checked the logcat to see if there are any relevant errors? Give us more details so we can help

Comment: The problem is that I simulate the Home Button before I start the other app.
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
  startActivity(i);
(This simulates the Home Button.)
When the other app is already running and this code is called the home button is simulated but the other app is not started.

Comment: Are you simulating the HOME button and then immediately calling `getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgname)` and `startActivity()`? If so, that's probably your problem. Have you tried manually pressing the HOME button and then executing your code (without simulating the HOME button)? is the behaviour the same?

Comment: Yes the behaviour is the same.

Comment: And another problem is that when I open a running app (without simulating the home button) then the start activity is opened and not the activity that is on the top. When i press back then the top activity is shown.

Comment: This is all hard to believe. Please post the manifest of your app and the app you are trying to start.